# Form Validation on submit using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to validate a form using javascript when the user submits the form, this is my code,

```js
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    var elements = document.getElementById("form").elements;
    var error = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
            //code
            if(elements[i].type == "checkbox" || elements[i].type == "radio") {
                var check_box = document.getElementById(elements[i].id).checked;
                  if (check_box == false) {
                      //code
                      error++;
                      var checkbox_div = elements[i].parentNode.parentNode.id;
                      produce_warning("you must agree to proceed", checkbox_div, elements[i].id);
                  }
            }
            
            else {
                if (elements[i].value == "" || elements[i].value == null) {
                    //code
                    error++;
                    produce_warning("you can not leave this field empty", elements[i].parentNode.id, elements[i].id);
                }
                
            }
    }
    
    if (error > 0) {
        //code
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
    
});
```

Here the event.preventDefault() statement is not executing, please help me thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by using the argument `event` in the callback function, try with `evt`,
demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/5c4gw4st/1/

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function(evt){
    var elements = document.getElementById("form").elements;
    var error = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
            //code
            if(elements[i].type == "checkbox" || elements[i].type == "radio") {
                var check_box = document.getElementById(elements[i].id).checked;
                  if (check_box == false) {
                      //code
                      error++;
                      var checkbox_div = elements[i].parentNode.parentNode.id;
                      produce_warning("you must agree to proceed", checkbox_div, elements[i].id);
                  }
            }

            else {
                if (elements[i].value == "" || elements[i].value == null) {
                    //code
                    error++;
                    produce_warning("you can not leave this field empty", elements[i].parentNode.id, elements[i].id);
                }

            }
    }

    if (error > 0) {
        //code
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }

});
```

Comment: @rayees in the fiddle provided as demo it does work, while with `event` does not

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have given my code here https://jsfiddle.net/rayees123/0r7ffudh/1/  please check it and suggest any corrections needed.

Comment: your code does not work because there is an error in it. at some point `document.getElementById` fails to match the given id. Easier to debug in locale though, just dig into it

Comment: thanks my friend you solution to debug the script works, i was trying  so hard to find a solution and finally i got it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use bracket notation:

```
if (error > 0) {
     //code
     event[preventDefault()];
}
```

Also check that event is an object.